# How not to stop asynctask when the activity finish

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an activity with an async task to send a file to a web service, if I am in the activity, I send the file, in the middle of the process I go to back to the activity, the async task finish. How can I make this not happen?

Comment: `AsyncTask` will be stopped by the system when the thread that started it completes.  If you want it to continue running, consider using `Service` instead.

Comment: Then, AsyncTask dont finish if i go to the back activity? If i have a Toast.maketext on onPostExecute and i am in other activity this will be show?

Comment: As long as the activity that started your task has not finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use progressDialog and set Cancelable to false in order to prevent that.